# How to expand an expandable menu on the whole page

Tags: css, layout

I'm a newby about css. I was experimenting some code. I would to create a kind of expandable menu just to "train" me like this.

[CodeOnJSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogjs9ev7/)

The code works but I would to expande the menu in the whole page but the property `width:auto` doesn't work. What is the rason and how could I make it happen in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a specified width on your children and expect the parent to fill up the width.

Since you know there are four links, you could set the width of the list items to 25%:

```
#menu li {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
```

If you also remove `width: auto` from `#menu` and `width: 150px` from the a-tags it should work.